# How to fix the lag in listeners for DefaultTabController

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi this is my first time asking a question here. Can someone please explain me on how to make defaulttabcontroller call his listeners when the gesture starts

Comment: Try testing performance in profile not debug

Answer (score 0):

The DefaultTabController is a predefined TabBar, in order to have more control of the listeners you should use the TabBar with a TabController, where you can add your listeners and custom behaviors.

```
...
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.tabController = TabController(length: 1, vsync: this);
    this.tabController.addListener(() {
      if (this.tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
...
}
```

and

```
TabBar(controller: this.tabController, tabs: [..])
TabBarView(controller: this.tabController, children: [..])
```